# Two dimensional continuous random variable and independecy

Tags: probability, independence, density-function

**Q**: Let $(X,Y)$ be a two dimensional random variable with the following density function:
$f_{_{X,Y}}(x,y)=\begin{cases}8xy&,  0\le x\le y \le 1 \\ 0&,  o.w.\end{cases}$

Are $X,Y$ independent?

**My attempts:** in the lecture notes I have, it says that two random variables $X,Y$ are independent $\iff \forall x,y \in \mathbb R: f_{_{X,Y}}(x,y) = f_{_X}(x)\cdot f_{_Y}(y)$.

I found $f_{_X}, f_{_Y}$:

- $
    f_{_X}(x)=\int_\limits{-\infty}^\infty f_{_{X,Y}}(x,y) \,dy=
      \begin{cases} 
        \int_\limits x^1 8xy\,dy&,  0\le x \le 1 \\ 
        0&, o.w. 
      \end{cases} 
    = 
    \begin{cases} 
      4x-4x^3 &,  0\le x \le 1 \\ 
      0&, o.w. 
    \end{cases}
  $
- $
    f_{_Y}(y)=\int_\limits{-\infty}^\infty f_{_{X,Y}}(x,y) \,dx=
      \begin{cases} 
        \int_\limits 0^y 8xy \,dx &,  0\le y \le 1 \\ 
        0&, o.w. 
      \end{cases} 
    = 
    \begin{cases} 
      4y^3 &,  0\le y \le 1 \\ 
      0&, o.w. 
    \end{cases}
  $

this is the part I'm not sure about:
$
  f_{_X}(x)\cdot f_{_Y}(y) =
  \begin{cases}
    (4x-4x^3)\cdot 4y^3 &  ,0 \le x, y \le 1 \\
    0 &, o.w.
  \end{cases}
$
so $f_{_{X,Y}}(x,y) \neq f_{_X}(x)\cdot f_{_Y}(y)$.

It's doesn't seem to be the right way to show the inequality. Also, what if the  equality was true? it's possible that the same function has two ways to be written.

So my question is what should I do to prove or disprove that $ \forall x,y \in \mathbb R: f_{_{X,Y}}(x,y) = f_{_X}(x)\cdot f_{_Y}(y)$, not only in this case but in the more general case.
Please keep in mind that I'm an undergraduate taking my first probability course, so please try to keep it simple.

Thanks

Comment: Your approach is the right approach and you shoud follow it in the general case also.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy , can you please elaborate? if for example I want to show that two cuntinuous random variables $X,Y$ are indepedent, that means that I need to get the **exact same** result for $f_{_{X,Y}}(x,y)$ and for $f_{_X}(x)\cdot f_{_Y}(y)$?

Comment: Yes, $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ a.e.  is necessary and sufficient for independence of $X$ and $Y$ provided the joint dendisty $f_{X,Y}$ exists.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy , Thank you. If you would make that comment as an answer I would be glad to accept it as an answer, as it is more suited for the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is right.  $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ a.e.  is necessary and sufficient for independence of $X$ and $Y$ provided the joint dendisty $f_{X,Y}$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the joint support

$$0\leq x \leq y\leq1$$

is a triangle.

A necessary condition for independence is that the support is Rectangular...thus $X$ and $Y$ cannot be independent